# Remote (Dell) printer errors

Tags: network, printing, vpn

When I configure and print to remote Dell printers, I get an odd errors in my `system.log`:

```
sandboxd[xxx] ([xxxxx]): DellSecureFilter(xxxxx) deny file-write-create /private/tmp/fx20140919212407.job
```

This occurs each time I attempt to print.  It works just fine for local network printers; only fails for printers that are connected by a vpn and on a different subnet.  These same printers work fine on Windows machines, so there is something going on with security somewhere that I'm not seeing.

Comment: "...only fails for printers that are connected by a vpn and on a different subnet..." I would bet that the vpn is the problem.

Comment: Apple product and OSX please.

Comment: Well, I do not believe this is a VPN problem.  I think the crux is that sandboxd is not allowing the creating and writing of files for this process to the tmp folder.  I think the question is ultimately, how can I change the permissions of a process in sandboxd to see if this resolves the problem and if ultimately Dell has a bug in the way they've written their daemon for OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was eventually resolved after about 6 months of complaining to Dell and Apple. A dell driver update was released that seemed to help the situation.